# Navigation bar for hierarchical navigation in wpf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

Hi there is a control in asp.net called **SiteMapPath** i need something similar in WPF to help users navigate back and forth through the application pages ...
does any one know about any third party control or built in features that can help me implement this feature or should i start from scratch

Being able to display journal history can do the trick too

Comment: journal history like breadcrumbs?

Comment: yes that's exactly what i want

Comment: a google search for [wpf breadcrumbs](https://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+breadcrumbs&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7GGLL_en) resulted in a couple opotions you may be interested in [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29350/WPF-BreadcrumbBar)  [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727382/breadcrumb-style-with-wpf-listview)

Comment: thanks Erick it helped alot but the problem is how can i bind navigationframe.backstack  to such controls

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more assistance at this point google searching is all I would be doing

Comment: Thanks, I figured out by myself ;)

Comment: Can you post the solution you found as an answer to your question and then if you can mark that as the answer instead of mine that would help the community

Comment: I figured out how to work with BackStack of the navigation controls and i am going to create a user control to work with that this weekend ... I will post the source codes as soon as i am done ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i created my own breadcrumb for wpf ...
First of all since all the navigation in my application were based on wpf **NavigationService** i used the **BackStack** property of the Frame

```
var x = Frame.BackStack.Cast<JournalEntry>().Select((page) => page).ToList();
```

Now it is just a matter of binding a listbox or whatever control you want to the Name property of the List above and in my case since i just needed to keep track of previous pages i added this code to the SelectionChanged event of the listbox bound to above List

```
void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = (sender as ListBox).Items.Count - (sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex;
        for (; i > 0 && (sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex != -1; i--)
            Frame.NavigationService.GoBack();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any WPF controls that work like the SiteMapPath. You could use a menu or a tab control to load different views onto the page and define the menus/tabs in xml. Below are a couple of links which may help spur you on to some ideas.
[WPF XML DataBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061358/wpf-xml-databinding)
[Bind to XLinq](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=50&cpage=1#comment-166001)

For Breadcrumbs you may be interested in
[code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29350/WPF-BreadcrumbBar)
[stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727382/breadcrumb-style-with-wpf-listview)